# `pracma`: collapse the matrix result of `detrend` for a single time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the `co2` data in R. I began by using `detrend()`. It seems to have worked, but it out putted the data in a time series format that R functions I try to use later on think it is a multivariate time series rather than a single. I want to keep it as a univariate time series. Here is my code. I have tried changing the data's format with no luck.

```
data(co2)
co2
plot(co2)

dmn <- list(month.abb, unique(floor(time(co2))))
co2.m <- matrix(co2, 12, dimnames = dmn)

co2.dt <- pracma::detrend(co2.m, tt = 'linear')
co2.dt <- t(co2.dt)
co2.dt
```

Here is one of the errors I get:

```
plot.ts(co2.dt)
```

> Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
>             cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"

Using `ts.plot` will get it to plot but it thinks it is a multivariate time series.

I would like it to plot as a single time series the way `co2` plots. Ideally I would like to change the format of `co2.dt` to the format of `co2`.

```
str(co2)
Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: 315 316 316 318 318 ...

str(co2.dt)
Time-Series [1:39, 1:12] from 1959 to 1997: -1.74 -2.11 -2.11 -2.11 -1.99 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" ...
```

They are both time series but slightly different and that difference seems to be disrupting a lot of the functions I try to use later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like it to plot as a single time series the way `co2` plots

```
co2.dt <- pracma::detrend(co2.m, tt = 'linear')
co2.dt <- ts(as.numeric(co2.dt), start = c(1959,1), frequency=12)

str(co2.dt)
# Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: -1.741 -0.608 -0.176 1.127 1.94 ...

plot.ts(co2.dt)
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer (on why `plot.ts` fails to work)**

The problem is that `plot.ts` will plot multiple time-series **on a panel**, rather than on a single graph. Then there is a maximum number of series that R can handle easily. The error message tells you that more than 10 series is not supported, while you have 12 (because after transposition you are looking at yearly data for each of 12 months). Use `ts.plot` instead:

```
ts.plot(co2.dt)
```

If you don't like `ts.plot`, then you need to split your time series into several groups, each on a new graphical window. For example, you can plot month 1-6 on one window, and month 7-12 on another.

```
plot.ts(co2.dt[,1:6])
x11(); plot.ts(co2.dt[,7:12])
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question: On  `start = c(1959,1)`, what is the 1 doing?